# How to search for latest file in a folder and search a string in the file?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to write a batch file with following actions:

1. Within a list of log files in a folder which generated everyday after each batch job runs like below:

   log_20170801_5.txt

   log_20170801_4.txt

   log_20170801_3.txt

   log_20170801_2.txt

   log_20170801_1.txt
2. Search for the latest log file generated today (e.g.log_20170801_5.txt)
3. In that log file, search for a string "Error"
4. If there is "Error" found, copy the whole row with Error and send out email with that row
5. If there is no "Error" found, send out another email

I have something like this:

```
set batch_name="HK Price Feed"
set today=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
set today_day=%date:~7,2%
set today_year=%date:~10,4%
set today_month=%date:~4,2%
set email_list=abc@abc.com
set log_path=C:\path\Log\
set string ="Error"

FOR /F %%I IN ("log_path") Do
    If findstr /i /r "%string%" 
        Echo Copy the Error Message row
        blat.exe -server  -f%email_list%     -to %email_list% -s "Error is find on %batch_name%" -body "Error Message row"

    ) ELSE  (
        blat.exe -server  -f%email_list%     -to %email_list% -s "No Error is found in the Log file"
        exit
    )
)
```

Can someone help me to correct the script to make it works?
- how to find the latest file for today generated?
- how to search for the string?
- how to copy the row with "Error" as variable?

Comment: Since the file names are suitable for sorting, use `dir /B /A:-D /O:D "log_????????_*.txt"`; parse the output of this command by a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) and assign the loop variable to a normal variable; so after the loop, the name of the newest file is stored in the variable; then use `findstr /I /R /C:"\<%string%\>"` to search the file for the given string. By the way, remove the _space_ in front of the `=` sign and change the quotation: `set "string=Error"`...

Comment: Hi aschipfl, thanks! May I know what is the script to copy the row with "Error" and stored as variable?

Comment: Simply capture the output of the command line `findstr /I /R /C:"\<%string%\>"` by another `for /F` loop and assign the loop variable to a normal variable; that variable will hold the last line containing `%string%` if there are multiple occurrences...

Comment: Don't [double-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45456240)!

Comment: actually I am very new to batch script, can you provide the sample script for that? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the latest file and search for string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456240/find-the-latest-file-and-search-for-string)