# Find the latest file and search for string

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have list of text files in a folder, I want to:

1. Find the latest file in the folder
2. In the latest file, find the string = "Error"
3. Copy the whole row with string = "Error"
4. If there are more than 1 Error found, copy as it as well

Script below very simple, I am very new to batch script, can help me to correct to make it work?

```
set today=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
set today_day=%date:~7,2%
set today_year=%date:~10,4%
set today_month=%date:~4,2%
set log_path=C:\path\Log\
set string=Error

    FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR %log_path%\*.* /A:-D /O:-D /B') do set LATEST=%%I
        If findstr /I /R /C:"%string%" %%I Do
        Echo Copy the Error Message row
            Else exit
```

Comment: Don't [double-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45436031)!

Comment: What do you mean by "copy the `whole row"? where do you want to copy it to? a file?

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit easier that you think. (and your `if` logic doesn't work at all)

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR %log_path%\*.* /A:-D /O:D /B') do set "LATEST=%%~fI"
findstr /I /R /C:"%string%" "%LATEST%"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR %log_path%*.* /A:-D /O:-D /B') do (
 findstr /I /L /C:"%string%" "%log_path%%%I" 
 goto done
)
echo none found!
:done
```

The `dir` yields the file NAMES only in reverse-date order, so the first file is the latest as required. This name is assigned to `%%I`

The `findstr` will then locate the required string, as a LITERAL (`/L`) within the file; name needs to be assembled from the directory as the `/B` switch on the `dir` command supplies name only. Put in quotes to allow the target path to contain separators.

Personally, I omit the closing `\` from pathnames and insert them where required. Since you've included the terminal `\` in the variable, your code would string together two `\`.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers already show how to find the latest (last modified) file in a directory ([`dir`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html), [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)):

```cmd
set "string=Error"
set "log_path=C:\path\Log"

for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D /O:D "%log_path%\*.*"
') do (
    set "latest=%%F"
)

findstr /I /R /C:"\<%string%\>" "%log_path%\%latest%"
```

The `findstr` command line returns all lines that contain the word `Error` in a case-insensitive manner (`/I`). The `\<` and `\>` in the search string denote word boundaries, so the search string must be a single word, so the string `Errors` does not constitute a match. This works only if regular expression search (`/R`) is done, which implies that you have to escape certain meta-characters like `.`, `*`, `^`, `$`, `[`, `]` and `\` in your search string by preceding with `\` to be treated literally.
If you want `Errors` to constitute a match, remove `/R` or replace it by `/L` to force literal search.

If you want to write the output of `findstr` to a file, use [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
findstr /I /R /C:"\<%string%\>" "%log_path%\%latest%" > "error_log.txt"
```